# Get user input, convert the data and then output it into a text box

Tags: c#, windows, forms

I'm trying to compile my first C# application (based on Visual Studio) ... also using Windows Forms for input (from user) and output.

User puts numbers into six text boxes (e.g. 2009 20 02 02:49:35) and then when the 'Convert' button is clicked, the program outputs E1234FB3278DC0 in a different text box.

Not sure if this is relevant but E1234FB3278DC0 = 63370694975000000 (in decimal).

oh also, I'm not sure about convertedText.writeline... should it be this.textBox7 = microseconds; ?

```
       String dateString = yyyy.Text + dd.Text + mm.Text + hh.Text + mm.Text + ss.Text;
        DateTime timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy dd mm  hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
        long ticks = timestamp.Ticks;
        long microseconds = ticks / 10;
        convertedText.WriteLine(microseconds.ToString("X"));
```

Thanks in advance..
And I gotta thank Luxspes for the orginal version.

Answer (score 1):

Some tips about this code snippet.

```
    String dateString = yyyy.Text + dd.Text + mm.Text + hh.Text + mm.Text + ss.Text;
    DateTime timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy dd mm  hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```

First of all, it's really strange that you use the same "mm"-object for months and minutes. The same problem with format specifier. To parse month you should use 'M'.

```
    long ticks = timestamp.Ticks;
    long microseconds = ticks / 10;
    convertedText.WriteLine(microseconds.ToString("X"));
```

So, if your date parsed successfully you'll get the number of microseconds that have elapsed since 12:00:00 midnight, January 1, 0001. It's E1234FB3278DC0 in hexadecimal (for the date in your question).
 But in your case date represented in the seconds. So, the number of microseconds will be always.

```
    timestamp.Millisecond*1000;
```

I have no idea about the type of convertedText object. But it seems to me that's not a problem.

Try to use the following code:

```
String dateString = yyyy.Text+dd.Text+M.Text+hh.Text+mm.Text+ss.Text;
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy dd M hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
long microseconds = dateTime.Ticks/10;
convertedText.Text = microseconds.ToString("X");
```

Comment: the type of convertedText is text box. but it's wrong somehow (got an error - System.Windows.Forms.TextBox' does not contain a definition for 'WriteLine')

Comment: hang in there, I just need to make sure it's working first. But I got an error when I click the 'Convert' button.

here's the new code:

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            String dateString = yyyy.Text + mm.Text + dd.Text + hh.Text + M.Text + ss.Text;
            DateTime timestamp = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString, "yyyy dd MM  hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
            long ticks = timestamp.Ticks;
            long microseconds = ticks / 10;
            convertedText.Text = microseconds.ToString("X");
        }

Comment: I see. Your code doesn't compile. Try to change: 1) date format: "yyyy dd M hh:mm:ss"; 2) add TextBox for minutes 3) use convertedText.Text property to assign text.

Comment: Ok, I've changed the format and a text box for minutes already exists. And I'm not sure what you mean by 'use convertedText.Text property to assign text'. I'm using: convertedText.Text = microseconds.ToString("X"); } Is this correct? 

It compiles fine, but when I click the 'Convert' button, I get this message: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Comment: Wait... what format do I change it to ? can you please post the code..? I'm completely new to c#..